# Excel Crashes, Repairs and Restarts itself when I delete worksheets programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with my excel. To begin with, I create worksheets dynamically based on some parameters and then I export the worksheets as PDF. So far everything is fine. Now, when I am done with worksheets and I don't need them anymore I want to delete them. When I run the code excel crashes, repairs and then restarts itself. I am wondering if anyone has any idea why this keeps happening. I also delete named ranges for each sheet just in case.

Btw, if I delete them manually everything is fine.

Here's the code

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim theName As Name
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
For i = 1 To unitsQty
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Info " & i)
    For Each theName In Names
        If (TypeOf theName.Parent Is Worksheet) And (newSheet.Name = theName.Parent.Name) Then
            theName.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("System Spec " & i)
    For Each theName In Names
        If (TypeOf theName.Parent Is Worksheet) And (newSheet.Name = theName.Parent.Name) Then
            theName.Delete
        End If
    Next
Next i
Dim myArray() As Variant

ReDim myArray(unitsQty * 2)
With Sheets("Tables")
    For i = 1 To unitsQty
        myArray(i - 1) = "Project Info " & i
        Debug.Print myArray(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To unitsQty
        myArray(i - 1 + unitsQty) = "System Spec " & i
        Debug.Print myArray(i)
    Next i
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArray(0)).Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArray).Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArray((unitsQty * 2 - 1))).Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I had a repeating-crash issue with a workbook once. For my situation, my code had somehow gotten corrupted. My fix, was copy/paste all the code to NotePad++ (not exporting) with notes on which module(s) the code came from, save the workbook as non-macro (.xlsx), **close and reopen**, then copy/paste code back in to correct modules.

Comment: have you stepped through to determine if a particular line causes the crash?

Comment: Just FYI, you are setting a value in `myArray(i-1)` but to test what is inside, using `Debug.Print myArray(i)`. I think you would want `Debug.Print myArray(i-1)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. So basically in the worksheets I had OLE Object and therefore every time I was trying to delete a worksheets I had "Can't enter break mode at this time" and when I clicked continue but excel was crashing.

Even when I tried to delete all objects from the worksheet before i deleted it,  excel still crashing.

I couldn't find any solution in the web, but I found a workaround that it is working fine and gives the desired results. The workaround is to copy the worksheets to a temp workbook and do all the work there and when I am done, i am just closing the workbook without saving it of course. That keeps my original workbook tidied up.